# Laravel validation allow image or pdf

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a file input in Laravel and I would like it to only allow images or pdf. How do I do this in controller validation?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'image' => 'image',
]);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should rather [make a MIME type validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-mimes):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif,svg,pdf',
]);
```

Comment: are these all the image mimes?

Comment: The Laravel image validation rule is doign the following: "The file under validation must be an image (jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg)"

Answer (score -3):

You may validate like below for different mime types:

```
    $allowed_mimes = [
         image/gif,
         image/png,
         image/jpeg,
         image/bmp,
         image/webp,
         application/octet-stream, application/pkcs12,
         application/vnd.mspowerpoint,
         application/xhtml+xml,
         application/xml,
         application/pdf
    ];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'image' => $allowed_mimes,
]);
```

See [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/validate-pdf-with-request/replies/87030).